# How to use newer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis reference in Roslyn analyzer targeting VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is it possible to upgrade the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis reference to something like version 1.3.x and still get the analyzer to load in VS2015?

I've got this setup working in my analyzer development environment so there seems to be some way for VS2015 to run analyzers that depend on Microsoft.CodeAnalyzer 1.3.1 for example.

However when I install the analyzer off the VSIX package to my office PC that doesn't have the VS SDKs installed VS complaisn that the extension "does not contain any analyzers". Now that I downgraded the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis references back to 1.0.0 everything works again.

How is targeting multiple VS versions supposed to work in the future in case each VS requires a reference to the same Microsoft.CodeAnalysis assembly that it uses internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.N packages work with Update N of Visual Studio, but there is no way to use 1.3 packages with something less than Update 3.

Comment: Oh, that explains. Also had no idea I was still running Update 1 on my office PC. Thanks for the quick response! I'm assuming this also means the packages are forwards compatible with 1.2.x working with VS2015u3 and VS2017 as well?